# Активация/деактивация кнопки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Не работает активация/деактивация кнопки на форме при клике на чекбокс. Проверил в на разных браузерах десктопных и в хроме мобильном все ок, но на стандартном браузере на андройде и в сафари iphone не работает. Пробовал через установку атрибута `formId.find('button.wpcf7-submit').attr('disabled', false);` если выбран чек-бокс и удаление `removeAttr(disabled)` если галочка снята. Пробовал и через свойство `formId.find('button.wpcf7-submit').prop('disabled', false);`, но бесполезно. Может подскажите как можно протестировать это. (знаю как только запустить средства разработчика в хроме телефона на компе, но как в дефолтном браузере, а тем более в iphone не знаю)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.browserstack.com/ - позволяет проводить тестирование с реальных девайсов. Там можно бесплатно попробовать 30 минут, как новый зарегистрированный пользователь.

Comment: Проверил в том сервисе, все работает. Пробую на реальном устройстве (iphone) не работает.